# url response time 

Tags: java, url, time, response

i am making a program to get the response time by any url...

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 for(int i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
       long starTime = System.currentTimeMillis();       
       conn.connect();

       long elasedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - starTime;
       System.out.println(elasedTime);

       conn.disconnect();
  }
```

but mostoff the time its giving me output result as 0.. plz someone help me out!!
i need to capture the time from last bit of my request to the first bit of response.

Answer (score 2):

Simply opening the connection isn't going to take any time at all.  You need to actually fetch the content from the URL to get a meaningful benchmark.  You've also moved `url.openConnection()` to *outside* of the benchmark loop, which is a bit bizarre.

So change your loop so that:

1. Move `url.openConnection()` inside the loop
2. Add a call to `conn.getInputStream()` after the `conn.connect()`.
3. (Maybe) read the contents of the `InputStream` - this may not be necessary, depending on what you're trying to measure
4. Most of all, read the JavaDoc for `HttpURLConnection` to properly understand what the methods really do.

Comment: i tried conn.getResponseMessage() but tat wont help me either

Comment: i used the conn.getInputStream() but still getting 0 values....not that much but still they are present in output

Comment: output:   
31
46
16
16
15
0
15
16
0
16
16

Comment: @rahul: So maybe the target server is caching, or using keep-alives, or something like that.  There's no such thing as a perfect benchmark.

Comment: isnt there any solution to this??

Comment: i also used conn.setUseCaches(false); but still same problem

Answer (score 1):

There's not much of a response that you could expect from merely opening a connection.

Moreover, your call to `connect()` is most likely ignored as your connection is already open -- that's why you get a 0 time. From the `URLConnection#connect()` javadoc:

> If the `connect` method is called when the connection 
>       has already been opened (indicated by the `connected` 
>       field having the value `true`), the call is ignored.

If you want to actually retrieve a response, fetch the `InputStream` (call `conn.getInputStream()`) and then read everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

Java api says the connection is made when you call the conn.connect() but the connection is not made unless you get the InputStream from the connection.

```
connection.getInputStream()
```

Comment: Add a call to conn.getInputStream() after the conn.connect() as mentioned by skaffman

Answer (score 0):

conn.connect() establishes a connection (TCP three-way handshake) but it does not "GET" the content at the URL. You can use Wireshark to verify this.

So know that with this method you are not measuring the response time to receive the content at the URL.